# How do I remove something I previously added with .after(content) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do:

Take a nav item - when it's clicked, add a "<" out to the side of it. 
Then when something different is clicked, I'd like to remove the "<" that I just added, so the newly selected item is the only item with the "<" next to it.

Simplified code:

```
$('.sidebar a').click( function() {
    //-->here I need to clear it off of any other items which have it
    $(this).after(' <');
});
```

(Incidentally, I recognize that I could do something with css, but that won't work in this instance. Needs to be js.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code

```
$('.sidebar a').click( function() {
    //Remove if there are any currently on the page
    $("#remove_later").remove(); 
    //Add to the link user just clicked onto
    $(this).after('<span id="remove_later"> &lt;</span>');
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/MHhp4/

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks - great idea.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$('.sidebar a').click( function() {
    //-->here I need to clear it off of any other items which have it
    $(this).after('<span id="remove_later"> <</span>');
});
```

and remove it with

```
$("#remove_later").remove();
```

?

Comment: In your example, you will leave the white-space, in most instances that would not be the problem but if white-space is set to pre, it could be a problem! In short, include the single space inside your <span>. Also, your code will NOT work as you are not checking and removing existing span tags before adding new.

Comment: I am sorry, but it's still not put together as it's supposed to. Move your remove code inside the click function and put it before the after function. Or just check my ans...